# How to perform unit tests for my spring boot controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tdd

I'm new into TDD, currently I'm learning a bit about how I can code automated tests to my spring boot APIs.

So, I have an application that recover a bunch of reports from my database.

I tried to use an custom test from a book that I'm reading. But the test doesn't work.

Always that I've tried to run my tests I got a exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 1 in XML document from class path resource [application.properties] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:258)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:257)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:107)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:243)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:178)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1471)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:963)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:532)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:77)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:428)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    ... 38 more
```

This is the test that I'm trying to run.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:application.properties")
@ActiveProfiles("local")
public class ReportControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void doesRecoverPercentageOfInfectedPatients() throws Exception {

        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(get("/api/report/infected").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();


        assertThat(result.getResponse().getStatus()).equals(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

Any suggestions or advice about how I can run this test properly or what I'm doing wrong?

For update:

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ReportApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReportApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My application.properties looks like this:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/zssn?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Comment: Could you give more info on your project setup? Is it xml or java configuration? Have you seen this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776669/failed-to-load-applicationcontext-from-unit-test-filenotfound

Comment: @Karapapas In my case I'm just using the application.properties file where I put all data to access my database and configurations to hibernate framework.

Comment: Could you paste your properties file? I think the error gives you a pretty good hint about the problem.
`Line 1 in XML document from class path resource [application.properties] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.`

Comment: @Karapapas I've added my application.properties at the end of my question. Is there something wrong?

Comment: Well the properties file seems fine. Is there any .xml file in your project? Maybe there is something wrong with the format of your xml files. What IDE do you use?

Comment: @Karapapas is there no .xml files. But I think that maybe I found the root of my issue. I'll make a quickly test and than I came back. About my IDE I use spring tool suit, the latest version.

Comment: Try to add `@ImportResource("classpath:application.properties")` right after `@SpringBootApplication` on your main class.

Comment: @Karapapas I found the issue. So the problem happened because the version of java that I've been using. I'm using the version 10 for a long time, and never got any kind of problem when I build my APIs. But now when I package my application I've notice that some classes don't have been compiled. So when I checked what classes was, I notice that those specific classes are not compatible with java 10 yet. So I've installed the version 8. The classes has been compiled and also my tests start to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and helpful talking I've figure out the problem.
So, actually I'm using Java 10, JUnit 4  and mockito 2.
My API works fine. But I've noticed some classes of hibernate have not compiled properly when I've tried to built the artifact, this happens because an the hibernate have not full support of Java 10 yet.

I've used this as my argument and found that JUnit and Mockito don't have full support to java 10 too.
So, all that I've did was change my development environment to Java 8, with that my tests start work properly.

That is the final version of one of my tests. I did some changes based on all advice that I've get on the comments.

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ReportControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext ctx;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.ctx).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void doesRecoverPercentageOfInfectedPatients() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/api/report/infected")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change ReportControllerTest as below. Need to remove `@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:application.properties")`

Also create application.local.properties under resource directory for your @ActiveProfiles("local")

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("local")
public class ReportControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void doesRecoverPercentageOfInfectedPatients() throws Exception {

        MvcResult result = mvc.perform(get("/api/report/infected").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();


        assertThat(result.getResponse().getStatus()).equals(status().isOk());
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @gaurav-srivastav I tried your suggestion, but I'm still get the same issue.

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot your using?

Comment: I'm using the version 2.0.2.

Comment: Junit Version? Use SpringRunner if you're using Junit4 or if using Junit 5 then use SpringExtension

Comment: Are you using XML definition for defining bean or application.properties?

Comment: I'm using application.properties. I'm tried use SpringRunner but still get the same.

Comment: Is there any application.local.properties file in resource directory? If you don't have that either create it or just remove @ActiveProfiles annotation. It will pick application.properties by default

Comment: In my case I don't have an application.local.properties so I remove the ActiveProfiles tag. Unfortunately I get the same thing. Just a note, I've notice that I cant use SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK, so I just using the @SpringBootTest without any additional properties. This can somehow doing this? I mean, I really have to use WebEnvironment.MOCK?

Comment: No you can use @SpringBootTest without additional info. Is it help you?

Comment: No. I'm still get: failed to load ApplicationContext.

Comment: Could you please share you Main class?

Comment: I've added my main class at the end of my question.

Comment: Application running exception test case?

Comment: No. Just tests to verify the status code for each request.

Comment: Sorry I was asking is your application working except test case?